# Unable to start spyder with user login

Tags: qt, anaconda, spyder

I have installed latest Anaconda distro. using sudo in ubuntu 14.04.

Initially it gave the error ***this application failed to start because it could not find or load the qt platform plugin xcb***.

After unsuccessfully trying several hints on google I stumbled across a suggestion to remove qt and pyqt.
I did ***conda remove qt and pyqt***. 
I then just by some wild guess did ***conda install qt and pyqt***. 
Spyderstarted loading. But it only loads if I login as root. From a user login it gives the same error message as earlier. 
Any idea what is wrong.

Comment: What does "conda" mean?

Comment: Conda is a package manager application that quickly installs, runs, and updates packages and their dependencies

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please remove your installation with sudo and install it in your home directory, as a regular user. That should fix the problem.

Comment: This could become a very tedious and complex task. After struggling much, I followed @CarlosCordoba advice and now its's set

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the owner of anaconda directory is same user.if not use the command

```
sudo chown -R sys2 /home/sys2/anaconda3/
```

here sys2 is user